# Switch from $a\cdot \sin(t) + b \cdot \cos(t)$ to $c \cdot \cos(t+f)$

Tags: trigonometry, education

How could I switch from $a\cdot \sin(t) + b \cdot \cos(t)$ to $c \cdot \cos(t+f)$?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use the addition formula for $c \cdot \cos (t +f)$ and compare coefficients.

Comment: Hi Hans, I found that $c=\pm sqrt(a^2+b^2)$ what solution must I choose? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your choice - adding $\pi$ to $f$ has the same effect.

Comment: @Hans Engler Hence I must choose plus if I add $\pi$ to $f$ and minus otherwise? Thank you a lot.

Comment: No, pick that value of $c$ for which you get the correct answer for $t = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

We see that by the addition formula,

$$c \cdot \cos(t + f) = c \cdot \left( \cos(t)\cos(f) - \sin(t)\sin(f)\right).$$

If you set $a = -\sin(f), c = 1,$ and $b = \cos(f),$ You can make a reasonable comparison between the expressions $a \sin(t) + b \cos(t)$ and $c \cdot \cos(t + f).$

Comment: In general you cannot set $c=1$. For $a=0$ and $b=5$ you will get $f=\pi$ and $c=5$. What one really gets from the comparison of the coefficients is a system of equations to solve: $$a = c \cdot \cos(f), \ b = -c \cdot \sin(f).$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
a\sin t+b\cos t=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left[\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos t +\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin t\right]$$

$$
=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left[\cos \alpha \cos t +\sin\alpha \sin t\right]$$

$$ =\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cos(t-\alpha). $$

$ (c,f) $ have different symbols.

Useful in combining two waves of same frequency but different amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

Set $t=0$, giving

$$a\sin(0)+b\cos(0)=b=c\cos(f).$$

Then set $t=\frac\pi2$, and

$$a\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)+b\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)=a=c\cos\left(\frac\pi2+f\right)=-c\sin(f).$$

This gives you the transfrom from $c,f$ to $a,b$.

You can invert it by noting that

$$a^2+b^2=c^2\cos^2(f)+c^2\sin^2(f)=c^2,$$ and

$$\frac ab=-\frac{c\sin(f)}{c\cos(f)}=-\tan(f).$$

---

Alternatively, the left expression cancels when

$$a\sin(t)+b\cos(t)=0,$$ i.e.

$$\tan(t)=-\frac ba.$$

This must coincide with

$$\cos(t+f)=0,$$ or

$$f=\frac\pi2-t,$$

$$\tan(f)=\cot(t)=-\frac ab.$$

Then, with $t=-f$,

$$-a\sin(f)+b\cos(f)=c,$$

$$c=-a\sin\left(\arctan\left(-\frac ab\right)\right)+b\cos\left(\arctan\left(-\frac ab\right)\right).$$